# How to bind pgm type connection in zeromq in android?

Tags: android, zeromq

I know how to do with tcp through zeromq in android app but i am looking for pgm type connection in ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [ZeroMQ build for Android](http://zeromq.org/build:android) page, there are two ways to use ZeroMQ with Android.

- Using JeroMQ, a pure Java implementation of the ZMQ protocol
- Using a native build of JZMQ (described on the wiki page)

According to the wiki "it is STRONGLY recommended to use the pure-java implementation of ZeroMQ" aka the first version. Unfortunately, the [JeroMQ GitHub README.md](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) reports that there doesn't exist an implementation of the PGM protocol for Java (see the Not Supported Features section).

So, to briefly answer your question you will need to make a native build of the JZMQ stack and possibly the [OpenPGM stack](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openpgm/) as well.